# ASP.NET Authentication over 3 sites on same domain

Tags: forms, authentication, cookies, forms-authentication

I need a Form authentication over 3 Sites (login.mydomain.com, www.mydomain.com and admin.mydomain.com). Users are from a MSSQL-DB, but I don't think that's a problem.

I've set up my web.config as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx , but it doesn't work.

My code for the login:

```
string RoleString = string.Empty;
RoleString = user.Gruppe.Bezeichnung;
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, user.Username, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2), false, user.Gruppe.name, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash);
cookie.Name = "UserCookie";
cookie.Domain = ".mydomain.com";
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
Response.Redirect("http://www.mydomain.com/Default.aspx");
```

What could be the problem? I tried with machine key in webconfig, but that gave me an error with the Viewstate of the MAC...

Comment: what's the exact error with viewstate/MAC?

Comment: it's the "Validation of viewstate MAC failed." Error